# URL with two forward slashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails project, in my `index` view, I have a link

```
<%= link_to 'Show all posts', show_all_path %>
```

In `routes.rb`, I have a route:

```
match "show_all" => "Posts#show_all"
```

When I click on that link, it goes from

```
http://<domain name>/my_rails_project
```

to

```
http://<domain name>/my_rails_project//show_all
```

It works. However, having two forward slashes doesn't look very nice. Can I make it so that only one forward slash appear?

EDIT: These are some of my files:

config/environment.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__) 
Blog::Application.initialize!
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
Blog::Application.configure do 
  config.cache_classes = false 
  config.whiny_nils = true 
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true 
  config.action_view.debug_rjs = true 
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false 
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false 
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log 
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin 
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "//pauls.scripts.asu.edu/blog/public" 
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw 
  do resources :posts match "show_all" => "Posts#show_all" 
end
```

Output of `rake routes`

```
show_all        /show_all(.:format)             {:action=>"show_all", :controller=>"Posts"}
```

Comment: Those are forward slashes, fwiw.

Comment: Can you show the `config/environment.rb` and your `config/environments/development.rb` files (assuming that's the environment you're using?) as well as all the uncommented sections in the `config/routes.rb` file?

Comment: can I have a look at your route file, if you customising the route, it might be you had an extra slash in your routes?

Comment: Please add to the question (not a comment) the output of 'rake routes'

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but why does your asset host start with `//`? It should either start with `http://` or the hostname.

Comment: @MarkThomas the `//` is a pretty rarely used shortcut, I actually only discovered it recently myself. It's a relative protocol shortcut for specifying a URL. So basically if you can load your application from `http://` or `https://`, by specifying `//`, it will just use whatever protocol that the site is currently being loaded from. This is useful because if you have a site using `https://`, then I believe it throws an error for resources not also served by SSL.

Comment: Assuming you're serving it with Passenger, what's the value of RailsBaseURI? It might be useful to try to reproduce this with a new app, served locally - see my answer below for some notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting the app to be served under a sub-uri? That's the most likely issue. Perhaps report back on exactly how you are doing that. Presumably you are not running this under webrick but under passenger on a server in dev mode?

What is the value of RailsBaseURI, or RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT, depending on what you are using, does it have a trailing slash? Check your apache/passenger config for trailing slashes anywhere on folders (document root in the virtual host too?). Try also outputting the value of root_url to see what that is.

As a simple test locally, make a new project and use a route something like this (note the scope):

Blog::Application.routes.draw do

```
scope 'my_rails_project' do
   match '/test',  :to => 'welcome#test'
end
```

end

And then a test action in a new posts controller:

```
 def test
    render :text => "ROOT-#{root_url}"
 end
```

That might shed some light on what is going wrong, by using simpler routes, and walking you through redoing the setup.

Then on your actual project, two things you can try, changing the ENV variable with which you are setting up the sub-uri, and verifying virtual host setup, and setting up a scope around all of your routes:

```
scope 'my_rails_project' do
   match '/show_all'=> "posts#show_all", :as => "show_all"
end
```

I would also try inspecting the output of show_all_path, to see what you're actually getting in your link, for example are you getting '//' in the href, or something else?

Comment: Haven't got time to try this, but I'll award the bounty to thank for your effort in answering anyway!

Answer (score 1):

when I use "match" this is the syntax that I use:

`match "/show_all" => "Posts#show_all"`

However I'm not sure if that forward slash would solve your problem. Give it a try?

Cheers

Comment: Bad luck.. that makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a rails issue. Rails do not know his own url. It knows only relative url of resources. These relatives urls are appened to the domain url. It does no generate an illegal url, so no error is raised.

So it look likes a virual host problem. But i can't tell you  what is exactly the problem. At some point your domain url is www.your_domain/rails_projects/.

You may change that, by updating your virtual host in order to get www.your_domain.

**Update :**

Here an example :

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
 DocumentRoot /www/subdomain/sub2
 ServerName www.sub2.domain.tld
 ServerPath /sub2/
 </VirtualHost>
```

will respond to :

```
http://www.sub2.domain.tld/sub2/
```

It looks like pretty similar to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this syntax?

```
match '/show_all'=> "posts#show_all", :as => "show_all"
```

:as option gives you correct path

```
<%= link_to 'Show all posts', show_all_path %>
```

Or maybe your default_url_options appending extra slash to end of the url.
Check your action controller.default_url_options

Comment: No, the :as option does not work. Still the same.

Where can I check action controller.default_url_options?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your Rails app is in a subdirectory. I'm not sure if it is related or not, but a quick search produced [this guide](http://kb.site5.com/ruby-on-rails/how-to-deploy-a-rails-3-application-to-a-sub-directory/) which may or may not solve your problem.

Comment: I don't see how that would help solve it, but thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an url like `http://<domain name>/my_rails_project/show_all` add this to your routes.rb

```
resources :posts
match "show_all", :to => "posts#show_all"
```

If you prefer an url like `http://<domain name>/my_rails_project/posts/show_all` add this:

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get "show_all"
  end
end
```

You can see more examples [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reproduce this with a blank application and post all the code on github, i think the error could be something else.

Please tell us your rails version and ruby version.